# Creating an alias in SQL Server before the FROM?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I saw that aliases can be used after FROM, for example,

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee as Emp
WHERE Emp.id = 10
```

I want a command which sets Employee ALIAS to Emp. I want to use it like this -

```
Employee ALIAS Emp -- is there a command like this ?
SELECT Emp.ColumnOne, Emp.ColumnTwo  
FROM Emp
WHERE Emp.id = 10
```

Does such a command exist ?

Comment: Is the current SQL syntax not comfortable to you?

Comment: @kmkaplan - just convenience. why type full table names after FROM ? Why not do it from the start. This will be nice for joins that involve a lot of tables.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - Now, i am confused. Is my question proper ?

Comment: @davidblaine The example you give shows the opposite: it is more verbose and I fail to see what convenience it brings.

Comment: @kmkaplan - I am not sure, but i think it is a good practice to write full names for the columns in the select statement. That is why i wanted an alias as early in the command as possible.

Comment: @davidblaine It is indeed good practice to explicitly spell out the columns you need. But you *can* `SELECT Emp.ColumnOne, Emp.ColumnTwo FROM Employee as Emp WHERE Emp.id = 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the “normal” syntax:

```
SELECT Emp.ColumnOne, Emp.ColumnTwo
    FROM Employee as Emp
    WHERE Emp.id = 10
```

Comment: Thanks, that works too and does not modify the database. Wow, it was unintuitive and unexpected.

Comment: There is a minor complaint though - when working in management studio, you will not get (edit) column names automatically next to emp, unlike when you use Employee. Maybe they should make a command like Employee ALIAS IS Emp.

Comment: @davidblaine You mean “column names” I presume. Anyways I can’t give you any help about this software as I really do not know it. But you could send them a feature request… After all it is the season for wishes :-)

Comment: What an apt comment. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 8):

What you want is called a [SYNONYM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx).

Note that this is a server-side object, and it will live in the database, not in the query definition.

Comment: Ah yes synonyms are more fit than views.

Comment: @kmkaplan - please include your answer as a comment so that readers can see alternate methods of doing the same thing, regardless of which is better.

Comment: SWeko - CREATE SYNONYM [ schema_name_1. ] synonym_name FOR <object>

Is this correct -

CREATE SYNONYM Company700 Emp FOR Employee

Comment: @davidblaine OK, I originally suggested using views: `create view Emp as select * from Employee`. But for your specific question synonyms could be better.

Comment: @davidblaine: `CREATE SYNONYM Emp FOR Employee` is good enough, it all is within the same schema. Synonyms are really useful when you have to work with more than one schema, though.

Answer (score 4):

From Microsoft SQL Server 2005  you can use [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
With Emp as (
  select * from Employee 
)
SELECT Emp.ColumnOne, Emp.ColumnTwo  
FROM Emp
WHERE Emp.id = 10
```

CTE is more powerful than you require in your question but match your syntax.